# CSS-menu issue in angular project

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to add a bootstrap menu to my angular 6 project. This is the code

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">User</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Customer</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">OL User</a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

The issue is, when I click customer link, URL redirect to the `localhost:4200/#`
and submenu is not opening. below code techniques, I used to project:

app.component.ts

```
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule],

})
```

Comment: tagged angularjs but is asking about angular - should be editted

Answer (score 2):

Local redirects in Angular are usually done by using routerLink:

From the [DOCS](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}" queryParamsHandling="merge">
  link to user component
</a>
```

More information about [Angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router)

---

You can use href if you want. But the biggest issue is that you haven't associated a component with a route.

Take a look at this [example](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-router-tutorial-setting-up-routing-in-your-application/)